# boost::thread_specific_ptr cannot access private member declared in class

Tags: c++, boost

I am wondering if there is a way to resolve following issue without changing the *ptr* access type.

```
class A
{
private:
    static boost::thread_specific_ptr< B> ptr;
public:
    boost::thread_specific_ptr< B> get() { return poolmanager_boost; }
};
```

Error:

```
boost::thread_specific_ptr<B>::thread_specific_ptr': cannot access private member declared in class 'boost::thread_specific_ptr<B>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `boost::thread_specific_ptr` is non-copyable and therefore cannot be returned by value. Either return a (const) reference to the member ptr:

```
const boost::thread_specific_ptr< B> & get() const { return ptr; }
```

Or return the contained pointer:

```
B * get() const { return ptr.get(); }
```